# java string split

Tags: java

What should I do if I want to split the characters of any string considering gaps and no gaps?

For example, if I have the string `My Names James` I want each character individually like this: `M y n a m e s` etc.

Comment: can you be more specific - what do you mean by "gaps"?

Comment: Some examples of both input and output would be useful.  As the question currently stands, I'm not sure anyone can answer it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mean this?

```
   String sentence = "Hello World";
   String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
```

Also if you would like to get the chars of the string you could do this:

```
char[] characters = sentence.toCharArray();
```

Now you just need a loop to iterate the characters and do whatever you want with them.

Here a link to the java API documentation there you can find information about the String class.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

I hope this was useful to you.

Comment: sorry my question was not complete....i wanted to mean if in a sentence like:My Names James....here I want each characters individually like:M y n a  m e s ...this way...

Comment: There it is char[] characters = sentence.toCharArray(); Then you can use a loop to filter or whatever...

Comment: Just iterate over the chars in the string?

Comment: Also he could do that, but i think he wants to store them first in a char[]

Comment: ok it worked!...now the next question is what function is there to replace a character with another one??

Comment: replace(char oldChar, char newChar). You have it in the api i gave you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MindFreak {
    static String makeSpaced(String s) {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if(!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                res.append(c).append(" ");
            }
        }
        return res.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(makeSpaced("My Names James"));
        System.out.println(makeSpaced("Very    Spaced"));

    }
}
```