# Retrieving integers from a string

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer

Say you have a string:

```
    String numbers = "123 11 4392034 2";
```

and you want to retrieve each integer in the string (separated by spaces).  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: I was thinking of making a substring(0, numbers.indexOf(space character), then making numbers = numbers.substring(indexOf);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524243/java-string-split

Comment: Thanks, this question clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split()` by space and `Integer.parseInt()` on each array element

Answer (score 2):

```
String numbers = "123 11 4392034 2";
String [] num = numbers.split(" ");
```

Then use this method to retrive the array of integers:

```
public int[] getIntegerArray(String[] numbers) throws NumberFormatException {
    if (numbers!= null) {
        int intarray[] = new int[numbers.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            intarray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
        }
        return intarray;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] tokens = "123 234".split("\\s")

for(String token : tokens){
  println Integer.parseInt(token)
}
```

**Links:**

1. Run the groovy script: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/1031001
2. Java Pattern class at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
3. Java regular expression tutorial  at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex

**Notes**

1. \s denotes white space character class, [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]. Extra '\' to escape the first one as '\' is itself an escape character. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html.